# How to FTP a file from windows to mainframe using C# code?

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp, mainframe

```
I want to FTP a file from windows path to mainframe path dev region(host-d2). Im not aware of mainframe,
```

so let me know how can i upload a file to mainframe in particular region like host-d2 using C# code.
    input parameters wil be 
    input_file path--> where input file is stored.
    FTP_Host -->host-d2
    useriD-->UserID
    password-->password
    here there will not be any ftppath, as the region is the only that will be considered in mainframe.

```
    enter code here
```

Comment: See [FtpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I'm assuming this particular mainframe is running the z/OS operating system, but please correct me if my assumption is incorrect.

If you can use FTP to upload a file from your C# program to any system, then it's the same with z/OS. Obviously z/OS's FTP server needs to be running, suitably configured, and network reachable. For security reasons you should use FTPS (FTP with TLS encryption, applied to both the control and data channels), and the ID and password you use should not be hardcoded and not stored "in the clear." And that's just really the bare minimum when it comes to security. Generally you'll want to transfer the file in binary mode, but ASCII (text) mode can be used if you want codepage conversion, in which case you should make sure you ask z/OS to apply your desired codepage conversion.

If you're uploading the file straight into z/OS zFS (UNIX file system) then that should be quite familiar, with UNIX/Linux-style directories and filenames. z/OS also supports z/OS Data Sets, which introduces concepts such as "records" and "record lengths." These are additional features in z/OS, but it's possible to send FTP commands to inform z/OS's FTP server how you'd like your file upload to be stored as a data set, in particular what the record length should be. Also, data set "directory" names are specified a little differently in the CD command than UNIX/Linux-style (and z/OS zFS) directory names are.

IBM provides ample documentation on the z/OS FTP Server including information on the commands it supports, but one basic approach if you're having trouble is to try to upload a file from a command line FTP client and check to see if you get your desired result on z/OS. If you don't get the desired result, refer to IBM's documentation or another tutorial, and try again.

There are many, many other ways to upload files to z/OS as well, if you prefer something else for whatever reason(s). Here are some examples, in no particular order:

1. You can mount a directory with a NFS client connected to z/OS's NFS server then simply copy the file to that mounted directory.
2. You can use z/OS's OpenSSH and SFTP.
3. You can use managed file transfer products such as IBM MQ Advanced (MQ Managed File Transfer) or Sterling Connect:Direct.
4. You can upload a file via HTTPS to the IBM HTTP Server for z/OS, included with z/OS.
5. You can PUT a file via the z/OS Management Facility's REST APIs for working with z/OS files. z/OSMF is also included with z/OS.
6. You can e-mail the file to z/OS, for z/OS to do something with it. There are at least a couple ways to do that, but one way is to use CASI Software's Mail2ZOS product.
7. You can not send a file at all, an inherently batch-oriented interaction. Instead, you can stream data in some fashion, for a more real-time (or near real-time) interaction. There are a variety of ways to do that; ask if you want more info.